# Effiecient way of displaying Real time graphs in ASP

Tags: c#, asp-classic, youtube

I want to display a Real-Time chart on a ASP web page. Right now i have used MS charts to display the chart along with AJAX which uses a .CSV file as a datasource. Data is being read from the CSV file present in the system and it is stored in an array(in the script running when the ASPX page is loaded) which is used to generate the graph. I want to know if this the right way to do it? Is it an efficient logic?
What exactly is done in sites like you tube? Can i use something similar to youtube to display the chart (like RTSP)?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is 
Make charts with fusion charts.  Please visit the url to have a look at the free charts offered by fusion charts.
Fusion chart = Javascript/Jquery + Ajax + CSS + Data 
All you need to call the functions and pass values as defined in fusion chart documents.
http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/chart-gallery/

Comment: Well i have already drawn a graph with an array that i am reading from the file. I am not sure what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I mean if it is efficient? like storing it in an array to display it real time. What if the server is sending around 18kb of data in every 30 seconds?

Comment: Use ajax .. Flexgird works on ajax. You can limit the data by introducing paging